# XPages pager control as custom control

Tags: xpages

My pager control is becoming complex with drop down to show page no. etc and other custom functionality. I thought of converting it to a custom control, but found that placing a pager on a custom control with partial refresh turned on, breaks the pager. Has anyone noticed this issue? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the a Pager custom Control in the Collaboration Today project. Works like a charm.
Important is the for property, the componentID who should be refeshed.
I pass this componentID to my custom Control thorugh a custom propery.
It works even a replacement of the standard pager of a view.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I will try to debug my code to see what's wrong, maybe it's the hidden pager control in my code causing issues (I use the hidden control to work out total no. of pages).

Comment: for that you don't need a extra hidden pager.

Comment: You can use getComponent("myRepeatControl").getRowCount()

Comment: This is what I am doing based on Rajeev's post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413530/custom-pager-in-xpages - but now trying to convert it to a custom control

Comment: I will try to build an example and post the source code here.